# Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed. java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space

Tags: android, android-studio-4.0, android-instant-run, instant-run, appinstaller

Many answers say to disable Instant Run but Cannot find Instant Run in android 4.0.1
Any help or knowledge would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

**below is the error I'm getting**

````
[0] 'D:\PC-name\Android\APL Android\APL-REPO\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --full -S 10837822' returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:
android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:501)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2415)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstallCreate(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:949)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:165)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:26073)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:642)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:540)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:3329)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4779)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:531)
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:447)
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:462)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSessionInternal(PackageInstallerService.java:660)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:499)
... 10 more''```
````

Comment: What you don't understand in "Not enough space"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your storage space on your device which it is running. After Clearing some space Try to Install or install it on an emulator.